# Add custom admin actions to django irrelevant to objects

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to add admin actions (for example with buttons) to django admin site that are irrelevant to particular model, for example doing administrative tasks such as optimizing database or clearing cache or log files or deleting records from multiple tables...
I have seen [django admin action without selecting objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500924/django-admin-action-without-selecting-objects), but the answers seems tricky and the solutions was selecting objects of particular model, in other ways.

Is there a better to add this functionality to admin site anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may [override Django admin's base template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) and add a block with buttons or links to your views.

Views do your logic, and then redirect the user back [to admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-reverse-urls).

There are some [tutorials](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-hack-redesign-customize-the-django-admin-with-bootstrap/) in Google too.